# Will a charge ballon get attracted to a conductor or insulator?

Tags: electrostatics, conductors, insulators

Will a inflated ballon charged by rubbing with fur get attracted to a conductor or an insulator ?

Comment: The balloon would attract e.g. human hair (maybe you have seen it in a physics lesson?). Is human hair an insulator or conductor?

Answer (score 1):

Both.

Let us suppose the balloon has a positive charge. It will exert attractive forces on electrons in both nearby conductors (metals, let's say) and nearby insulators.

In the case of **metals**, because of the attractive force, some free electrons will move through the metal giving the surface of the metal nearest the balloon a negative charge. So the balloon will be attracted towards the metal. Two further points...

• There will be positive charge on the metal due to migration of free electrons but this charge will be further from the balloon, so the repulsive force that it exerts on the balloon will be smaller than the attractive force from the (nearer) free electrons.

• If the balloon actually touches the metal it might be thought that electrons would flow from the metal on to the balloon and neutralise its positive charge. This will take place only on the small part of the balloon's surface that is in contact with the metal, because the balloon skin is an insulator so parts of the skin not in contact with the metal will stay charged.

In the case of **insulators** near the balloon, although there are no free electrons, molecules of the insulator will be polarized. In other words, the molecules will be slightly distorted, with electrons pulled slightly towards the balloon and positive nuclei pushed slightly away. This means that each molecule will exert a small resultant attractive force on the balloon, and these force add together. So the balloon will be attracted, though not as strongly as to a conductor of the same shape the same distance away.

Answer (score 0):

Both.

Due to electrostatic induction, the charged balloon will pick up small pieces of aluminium foil (conductors), and small pieces of paper or salt and pepper (isolators).

Because of Newton's third law, the balloon is simultaneously attracted to those conductors or isolators.